# Breaking change when adding Routes in MVC 5.2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I updated from an older ASP MVC Version to 5.2.2

In my code i'm cloning existing attribute routes for localisation support.

So If i've a route like "/Hallo" it would be "/Hello" for an english culture.

My Code looks like this

```
 var localizedRoute = new Route(slug, defaults, constraints, tokens, originRoute.RouteHandler);
 routeTable.Add(localizedRoute);
```

since the update i got a exception when i try to open a url which is related to such a route. It told me that i should set an route handler so i change my code to this:

```
var localizedRoute = new Route(slug, defaults, constraints, tokens, new MvcRouteHandler());
```

But then I got a 404 when i open the url

i also tried to use

```
var result = target.MapRoute(key, slug, defaults, constraints);
```

instead of adding it directly same result.

What am i doing wrong?

I'm thinking about trying the IDirectRouteProvider interface. CAn someone tell me if this would be a better way ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.idirectrouteprovider.getdirectroutes(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: aside - localizing routes can be troublesome. the routes only get added at app start up which has the first language provided.

Comment: thats ok i've a list of supported cultures / languages and for that i add the routes. After that they are fixed. It also worked in the olrder version i think it was 5.0.0